# Rewrite Mod Still Returns Original URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using WamServer , I used [Generate It!](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) to over write a URL like

The original URL:

```
http://localhost/CMS/foo.php?id=2&slug=eyeglasses
```

The rewritten URL:

```
http://localhost/2/eyeglasses.php
```

The rule which site gave me is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /CMS/foo.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

but this is still returning original URL

```
http://localhost/CMS/foo.php?id=2&slug=eyeglasses
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

> Update

To be more clarify! I have an `index.php` which contains a link like

```
echo '<a href="foo.php?id='. $theID .'&slug='. $slug .'" class="list-group-item" data-id="'.$theID.'">'.$theName.'</a>';
```

now we user landed in `foo.php` the URL looks like

```
http://localhost/CMS/foo.php?id=1&slug=eyeglassess
```

correct? what I would like to do is displaying the

```
http://localhost/2/eyeglasses.php
```

instead of original URL

Comment: Please clarify. Are you sending the URL `http://localhost/CMS/foo.php?id=2&slug=eyeglasses` from the browser, and expecting it to be rewritten in the browser address bar to `http://localhost/2/eyeglasses.php`, or are you sending `http://localhost/2/eyeglasses.php` from the browser and it is redirecting rather than rewriting internally to `http://localhost/CMS/foo.php?id=2&slug=eyeglasses`? If the first issue is what you're seeing, that's not how mod_rewrite is normally used, and requires a few additional lines to formulate.

Comment: In other words, mod_rewrite cannot transform URLs in your code or out in the wild automatically. It's usually used to route a clean URL to something more complicated in your application.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I actually have a `index.php` page and I have link ` echo '<a href="foo.php?id='. $theID .'&slug='. $slug .'" class="list-group-item" data-id="'.$theID.'">'.$theName.'</a>';` to the `foo.php` now in foo.php instead of having `http://localhost/CMS/foo.php?id=2&slug=eyeglasses` I would like to have `http://localhost/CMS/foo.php?id=2&slug=eyeglasses` in the URL

Comment: @anubhava, can you please also read the above note?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a redirect rule to redirect old URL to pretty URL. This code should be in `/CMS/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /CMS/

# redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /CMS/+foo\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&slug=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2.php? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.php$ foo.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

However it is better to change your link code to new pretty link scheme.

Comment: thanks this exactly what I am looking for but! why I am getting `Not Found`  page!

Comment: is there any way to get rid of the id? I mean to keep it juts like `http://localhost/eyeglasses.php`

Comment: Oh I see! we are missing the `/CMS/` file name

Comment: I guess it should be! but why do we need the ID?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96178/discussion-between-behseini-and-anubhava).